# framework7 stuck at executing npm scripts and start npm throws a bunch of errors

Tags: node.js, vue.js, html-framework-7

i am new to the framework and was just going through a tutorial and encountered by an error after pressing create app in the local host
Generating package.json

```
✔ Creating required folders structure
✔ Installing NPM Dependencies
✔ Installing NPM Dev Dependencies
Executing NPM Scripts
```

this happens its stuck at executing NPM scripts waited a whole 3 hours still executing

---

The start npm command shows the following:-

```
> whatchat@1.0.0 start C:\Users\piyush\whatchat
> npm run dev


> whatchat@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\piyush\whatchat
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\build\webpack.config.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js
- C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\piyush\whatchat\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:84:40) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\piyush\\whatchat\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\utils\\convert-argv.js',
    'C:\\Users\\piyush\\whatchat\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! whatchat@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the whatchat@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\piyush\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-15T14_13_28_671Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! whatchat@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the whatchat@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\piyush\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-15T14_13_28_828Z-debug.log
```

i searched lot on Google and discord coding help servers but could not fix this please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably didn't install `cordova` before try:

```
npm install -g cordova
```